Benchmarking type generic algorithms on type heterogenous problem sets in Rust
I need to benchmark the different code generations of a generic function in rust, for different type parameters. I ran upon this when developing differential equation solvers using nalgebra. I have various initial value problems (different float types and different vector shapes), and want to run all my algorithms on these. For each problem, the relevant instantiation of the algorithms must be found and applied.
My solution is creating a manual HashTable from the TypeId of the problem generics to the relevant instance of the solvers. To explain this method, I have created an artificial problem set about matrix multiplications. See this rust playground link, also presented as the enclosed code below.
I want advice on how to improve the maintainability of the code so that adding a new type parameter, a new problem set, or a new solver won't lead to extensive modifications at multiple places in the code. Any suggestion to reduce the risk of manual errors would be appreciated.
To be more explicit: The module multipliers represent the algorithms to benchmark. I do not want to change anything in the code therein. It is the code in bench_utils and the hashtable construction/lookup of main that I want advice on. Or maybe you have a completely different approach that solve the same problem.
use nalgebra as na; // 0.32.3
#[allow(non_camel_case_types,non_snake_case)]


mod bench_utils{
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    use nalgebra as na;
    
    /// Generic problem description
    /// They all represent two matrices A and B that needs to be multiplied
    /// The resulting matrix is always 3x3
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct GenProb<T,D>
    where
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> 
    {
        pub name: String,
        pub A: na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,
        pub B: na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>
    }
    
    /// Generic solver description
    /// A matrixnamed multiplication algorithm
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct GenSolv<T,D>
    where 
    T: na::Scalar,
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> 
    {
        pub name: String,
        pub solver: fn(na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>) -> na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,na::Const<3>>
    }
    
    /// The generic problem type instansiated for all at compile time known type value
    pub enum Problem {
        P_1_64(GenProb<f64,na::Const<1>>),
        P_1_32(GenProb<f32,na::Const<1>>),
        P_5_64(GenProb<f64,na::Const<5>>),
        P_5_32(GenProb<f32,na::Const<5>>),
        P_dyn_64(GenProb<f64,na::Dyn>),
        P_dyn_32(GenProb<f32,na::Dyn>),
    }
    
    impl Problem {
    
        /// TypeId of the wrapped Generic Problem type
        pub fn type_id(&self) -> std::any::TypeId {
            match self {
                Problem::P_1_64(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<1>>>(),
                Problem::P_1_32(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<1>>>(),
                Problem::P_5_64(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<5>>>(),
                Problem::P_5_32(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<5>>>(),
                Problem::P_dyn_64(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Dyn>>(),
                Problem::P_dyn_32(_) => std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Dyn>>(),
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// The generic solver type instansiated for all at compile time known type value
    pub enum Solver {
        S_1_64(GenSolv<f64,na::Const<1>>),
        S_1_32(GenSolv<f32,na::Const<1>>),
        S_5_64(GenSolv<f64,na::Const<5>>),
        S_5_32(GenSolv<f32,na::Const<5>>),
        S_dyn_64(GenSolv<f64,na::Dyn>),
        S_dyn_32(GenSolv<f32,na::Dyn>),
    }
    
    pub fn process<T,D>(prob:GenProb<T,D>,solv:GenSolv<T,D>) where
    D: na::Dim,
    T: na::RealField,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>>,
    {
        let now = std::time::Instant::now();
        let _C = (solv.solver)(prob.A,prob.B);
        let elapsed = now.elapsed();
        println!("Running {:10} on {:15} took {:?} seconds",solv.name,prob.name,elapsed)
    }
}

mod multipliers{
    //! A module containing matrix multiplication methods
    
    use nalgebra as na;
    use nalgebra; // 0.32.5

    /// The built in matrix multiply
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    pub fn na_star<T,D>(
        A: na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,
        B: na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>
    ) -> na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,na::Const<3>>
    where
    T: na::RealField,
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> {
            A * B
    }
    
    /// An alternative implementation
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    pub fn manual<T,D>(
        A: na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,D>,
        B: na::OMatrix<T,D,na::Const<3>>
    ) -> na::OMatrix<T,na::Const<3>,na::Const<3>>
    where
    T: na::RealField + std::iter::Sum + Copy,
    D: na::Dim,
    na::DefaultAllocator: na::allocator::Allocator<T, na::Const<3>, D>
     + na::allocator::Allocator<T, D,na::Const<3>> {
        let mut out = vec![];
        for r in 0..3 {
            for c in 0..3 {
                out.push(
                    A.row(r).iter().zip(B.column(c).iter()).map(|(&a,&b)| a*b).sum()
                )
            }
        }
        na::Matrix3::from_vec(out)
    }
}

use bench_utils::*;

pub fn main() {

    let problems = vec![
        Problem::P_1_64(GenProb{name:"1 64 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x1::new(0.0, 1.0, 2.0),B: na::Matrix1x3::new(2.0, 1.0, 0.0)}),
        Problem::P_5_64(GenProb{name:"5 64 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x5::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0),B: na::Matrix5x3::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)}),
        Problem::P_1_32(GenProb{name:"1 32 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x1::new(0.0, 1.0, 2.0),B: na::Matrix1x3::new(2.0, 1.0, 0.0)}),
        Problem::P_5_32(GenProb{name:"5 32 static".into(), A: na::Matrix3x5::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0),B: na::Matrix5x3::new(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0)}),
        Problem::P_dyn_64(GenProb{name:"1 64 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]), B: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]) }),
        Problem::P_dyn_64(GenProb{name:"5 64 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]), B: na::Matrix::<f64,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]) }),
        Problem::P_dyn_32(GenProb{name:"1 32 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<_,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]), B: na::Matrix::<_,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![0.0,1.0,2.0]) }),
        Problem::P_dyn_32(GenProb{name:"5 32 dyn".into(), A: na::Matrix::<_,na::Const<3>,na::Dyn,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]), B: na::Matrix::<_,na::Dyn,na::Const<3>,_>::from_vec(vec![1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]) }),
        ];
    let solvers: std::collections::HashMap<_, Vec<_>> = std::collections::HashMap::from([
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<1>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_1_64(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_1_64(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Const<5>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_5_64(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_5_64(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f64,na::Dyn>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_dyn_64(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_dyn_64(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<1>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_1_32(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_1_32(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Const<5>>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_5_32(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_5_32(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        (std::any::TypeId::of::<GenProb<f32,na::Dyn>>(),vec![
            Solver::S_dyn_32(GenSolv{name:"nalgebra*".into(),solver:multipliers::na_star}),
            Solver::S_dyn_32(GenSolv{name:"manual".into(),solver:multipliers::manual}),
        ]),
        
    ]);
    for prob in &problems{ 
        let id = prob.type_id();
        for solv in &solvers[&id] {
            match (prob,solv) {
                ( Problem::P_1_64(p), Solver::S_1_64(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_5_64(p), Solver::S_5_64(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_dyn_64(p), Solver::S_dyn_64(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_1_32(p), Solver::S_1_32(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_5_32(p), Solver::S_5_32(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                ( Problem::P_dyn_32(p), Solver::S_dyn_32(s))=>process(p.clone(),s.clone()),
                _ => eprintln!("This problem/solver pair is not compatible")
            }
        }
    }
}


I have little time, so this'll be short.
Tools
Rust comes with a number of useful tools, by default. In particular:

cargo fmt will call rustfmt, which will format your code so it looks like any other code.
cargo clippy will lint your code, warning about potential mistakes, unidiomatic or needlessly complicated code, etc...

I would advise running both on your codebase.
Benchmarking
Benchmarking is a tad more complicated than just measuring the elapsed time. Some workloads will sometimes be faster, sometimes slower, etc...
Using a benchmarking library such as criterion will allow you to get a more trustworthy measure of the time taken to run a specific piece of code on a specific piece of data, by running it multiple multiple times and performing some statistical analysis on it. Not only will you get the average time, but it'll also show outliers (too short/too long), and if you run it a second time, it'll also tell you whether it improved or slowed down.
Over-complication
The Vec and HashMap look wholly unnecessary.
You may as well just use plain functions: one function per problem, calling one closure per solver, or something similar. There's no need for first mapping everything out in data-structures and then looping over and using the mapping.
